# return value on ajax comes back with 0

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to run a conversion in Ajax.  I believe from what i found online, I have most everything correct.  However when I use the calculate button, It returns 0 in my results div, instead of answer.  I think the issue is my numeric value isn't getting properly pulled from the text box.  I need to do it like this, so changing html input types isn't an option.  I am extremely new to Ajax, and don't quite know how this works.  Any help would be great.

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Money Conversion</title>

<script>
var http = createRequestObject();

function createRequestObject() {
    var ro;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
        ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return ro;
}


function moneyConversion(argLB) {

    http.open('get', 'Conversion.php?pound=' +argLB);
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() {

    if(http.readyState == 4){
      result = http.responseText.split(",");
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = result[0];

    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<form name="myForm" action="#">
  <h1>Enter amount of Dollars You Want To Convert to Pounds</h1>
   <input type="text" name="txtCurrency" />
   <input type="button" name="calcBtn" value="Calculate" id="calcBtn" onclick="moneyConversion()" />
</form>
</div>

<h1>Total</h1>
<div id="results">


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

my function conversion.php

```
<?php

$dollars=$_GET["pound"];
$conversion=($dollars * .6302);
print ("$conversion");``

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick="moneyConversion()"
```

should be

```
onclick="moneyConversion(this.form.elements.txtCurrency.value);"
```

otherwise you passing empty string to php

Comment: That did it, thank you so much.   I had a feeling I wasn't passing a value from the text box, but i couldn't figure  out how to do it.  Thanks again.  I will green check it in 6 min when it lets me.